# float java-me j2me

Tags: java-me, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - simple division in Java ---> bug/feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909451/java-simple-division-in-java-bug-feature)

anyone know bigdecimal in j2me midp 2.0?

actually i just want to make j2me app, which is able to compute 1 / 6.
and print it as 0.1666667. just like embedded calculator in many(every) mobile phone.

i use float it prints 0.0
i use double it still prints 0.0

many thanks.

Comment: See [Java - simple division in Java ---> bug/feature?!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2909451/47773).

Comment: @Vuntic - remember that we were all once and on many levels still are where OP is now. *Every man is my superior in some way. In that, I learn of him (Emerson)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vuntic: yeah..., this is stupid question ever.
@Matt: thx, now i know the answer referring from the link question...

just cast it to float.. (float) 1 / (float) 6

Comment: Or you can use float literals, like `1.0f / 6f`.