# How to output the decimal in average?

Tags: java, while-loop, sum, average, sentinel

I have a problem in showing the decimals on the average. It keeps showing .00 or .1.
I tried to put it in double, but I still get the same results.Also, I want to include the first integer that I input to the sum, but I have no idea how.Please help:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WhileSentinelSum 
{
static final int SENTINEL= -999;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Keyboard Initialization
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variable Initialization and Declaration
        int number, counter;
        int sum =0;
        int average;

    //Input
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: " );
        number = kbin.nextInt();
        counter=0;


    //Processing
    //Output
        while(number != SENTINEL)
        {
            counter++;
            System.out.print("Enter an  integer number: ");
            number = kbin.nextInt();
            sum += number;
        }

        if (counter !=0)
            System.out.println("\nCounter is: " + counter);
        else
            System.out.println("no input");

        average= sum/counter;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);


        System.out.println();

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: `average` must be a `double`. At the assignment of average, do this computation: `average = (sum + 0.0)/counter;`

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909451/java-simple-division-in-java-bug-feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you declared `average` to be `double`, the `sum` and `counter` variables are `int`, so Java still uses [integer division](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) before assigning it to `average`, e.g. `5 / 10` results in `0` instead of `0.5`.

Cast one of the variables to `double` before the division to force a floating point operation:

```
double average;

...
average = (double) sum / counter;
```

You can include the first number in your calculation by processing it before you go into the while loop (if it's not the sentinel value).

Comment: Thank you,how to add the first integer that I input to the sum?

Comment: The same way you add into the sum in your while loop.

Comment: its giving a different answer

Comment: Different as in incorrect?  Make sure you _count_ that first number too.

Comment: i did..Enter an integer number: 1
Enter an  integer number: 1
Enter an  integer number: 1
Enter an  integer number: -999

Counter is: 3.0
The sum is -1996.0
The average is -665.3333333333334

Comment: Then you'll have to debug your application to ensure that all 3 ones are being counted and summed, and that the sentinel value _isn't_ being counted and summed.

Answer (score 1):

```
average = sum/counter;
```

This line is performing *integer division* (i.e. it cuts off the decimal part of the true result). You should change it to

```
average = (double) sum / counter;  // perform double division, not int division
```

which first casts `sum` as a `double` and, consequently, performs regular double division.

Note that you will need to change the type of the `average` variable to `double`.

---

Just to illustrate my point:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;

System.out.println(a / b);
System.out.println((double) a / b);
```

```
1
1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is in the line that says

```
average = sum/counter;
```

Even if you make `average` a `double`, `sum/counter` is still integer division which will yield an integer answer. You could try saying

```
double average = ((double)sum)/counter;
```

Another solution would be to make `sum` or `counter` of type `double` and also make `average` a `double`.

Comment: Technically speaking, there is no need to enclose `(double) sum` in parentheses... The cast will be applied to _sum_ regardless.  That being said, you can make an argument _in favor of_ the parens by saying it's more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize sum and average to double.
Use kbin.nextDouble().

Comment: It's probably  better to leave them as ints, but to cast one of them to a double for the division.

Answer (score 0):

It is said: **Never use `double` or `float`, when exact results are needed.** You should prefer `BigDecimal` instead. the primitives don't use a rounding mode most poeple would expect.