# How do I make this program return numbers after the decimal?

Tags: java

This program works but when I input my numbers it return numbers with only .0 (ex 1.0, 2.0, 3.0) when i want it to give the correct number after the decimal.

I know it has something to do with the numbers being integers but Im not sure how to go about converting. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Sorry if its confusing. What I want is the program to give me the results in the format of ex. 5.7 or 4.9 or 2.4 but the program returns only 1.0 or 4.0 or 6.0

```
package hw3;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovingAverage {
    private QueueX queue;
    private int size;
    private long sum = 0;

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public MovingAverage(int size) {//
        this.queue = new QueueX();
        this.size = size;
    }

    // checks sum, size and average of the queue
    public double next(int val) {
        sum += val;
        queue.enqueue(val);
         if (queue.size()<=size) {
            return sum/queue.size();
        }

        sum-= queue.dequeue();
        return sum/size;
        
    }

    // DO NOT CHANGE THE MAIN METHOD
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to specify the window size: ");
        int window = input.nextInt();
        MovingAverage m = new MovingAverage(window);

        ArrayList<Double> arrList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < window + 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number to be added into the window: ");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            double avg = m.next(num);
            System.out.println("The average after adding the above number is: " + avg);
            arrList.add(avg);
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Averages in the sequence are: " + arrList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what "it returns numbers" means.  Are you talking about your two print statements?  I assume that you are, but I think it is good to be sure we know what we're talking about.

Comment: While next() returns a double, ``sum / queue.size`` is a long because it uses integer division.

Comment: Yes im talking about the print statements

Comment: You should look up Double.format(). The problem is that unless you do a proper division, your average will never have digits after the decimal place.

Comment: I now think I get what you are asking, and I think @NomadMaker has nailed your problem.  You are using and printing numbers that technically can have fractional components, but your logic leads to them only ever containing whole integers.  This happens because you are doing an integer math calculation and expecting it to lead to a value with a fractional component.

Comment: You can fix the case that @NomadMaker points out in a number of ways.  What I'd do is cast `sum` to a `double`, and so do `(double)sum/queue.size()`

Answer (score 1):

Take this line of code:

```
return sum/queue.size();
```

There's a lot going on here.

`sum` is a long. `queue.size()` is an int. The method's return type is `double`, so whatever happens here, somehow it all ends up as a double.

The way java works is in this exact order: First, `sum/queue.size()` is resolved to whatever it is, and only after that's all done does the next step ('make that a double') kick in. Which is too late.

`x / y`, where x is an int and y is a long, is done by first upgrading x to a long, and then doing integer division: Do the division, and just take an axe and lop off the decimal part (so, round down for positive numbers, but round up for negative numbers).

So, let's say your sum is 18, and your count is 4, you do 18/4 which is just 4. Not 4.5.

This 4 then gets turned into a double, so now you have 4.0.

### Fix to first of your two problems

Make your counter a double first: `return sum / (double) queue.size();`. Now it's 'divide this long by this double' which is done by converting the long to a double and then doing the division, which will get you 4.5.

But, you have a second, more complicated problem. A double is a datatype of 64-bit. Using basic logic, that means that there are only at most 2^64 different numbers in existence that can be represented by a double. Which is a problem; you'd think that literally every possible number ever can be represented by it, but **that is not true**. Instead it's a set of 'blessed numbers' which can be represented by double (and the closer you are to 0, the more blessed numbers there are). Any result of any double-based operation is **silenty** rounded to the nearest blessed number. Blessed numbers are annoying in that they make some sense if looking at in binary, but not in decimal, so weird stuff (like 0.1+0.2) doesn't even work right.

### Fix to the second

That means that doubles tend to have errors in them, and you need to print them only by specifying how much error you expect. This is best done with format: `String.format("%.5f", theDouble);` will format according to the rule: No more than 5 digits after the comma.

Alternatively, if you want perfection, there is `BigDecimal` but note that division is tricky (1/3 is 0.3333333 - infinite, so without configuring rounding rules, cannot be done to a BD).

Answer (score 0):

```
public double next(int val) {
    if(queue.size() == size)
        sum -= queue.removeFirst();

    queue.addLast(val);
    sum += val;

    return (double)sum / queue.size();
}
```

Whey you want to use `/` pay attention on arguments. At least one of the should be `double` or `float`.

```
int a = 9;
int b = 2;
double res = a / b;    // 4
```

*i.e. `9 / 2 = 4` - and then convert this value to double `4.0`*

```
double a = 9;
int b = 2;
double res = a / b;    // 4.5
```

*i.e. `9.0 / 2.0 = 4.5` - first convert all operands to `double` then do division*

In case of both arguments `int` (or `long`), then

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but if you want to display the numbers as normal integers without decimal points then it has something to do with you using double as avg and in your array list variables. If that was indeed your intention to use double but not display as such then while printing, ie, in your sout you can replace the value from `var` to `(int)var` or even `(int)Math.round(var)` (for you to round it off incase you have some fractions when avg is being calculated).

Comment: Sorry if its confusing. What I want is the program to give me the results in the format of ex. 5.7 or 4.9 or 2.4 but the program returns only 1.0 or 4.0 or 6.0

Comment: Ah okay. Then in your next() function, you are doing a integer division when you are returning a value. Hape a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909451/simple-division-in-java-is-this-a-bug-or-a-feature

Basically have the numerator type-casted as double and it should work